# how to create list of test and train data frame from list of data frame

Tags: r

I'm trying to create multiple test and train data sets from mulitple data frames in a list. Hence, I'm getting this "Error in 1:nrow(df) : argument of length 0" and don't understand how to solve it. I have manually updated the list with out the for loop and it works fine. But for some reason when I try to repeat this process using a for loop I get the error.

I first created a 3 three mini data frames from the iris data set

```
x <- 3;
# split the data into 3 mini data frames
set.seed(1)
df_list<- split( as.data.frame(iris), sample(x,nrow(iris),replace=TRUE))
```

Than an empty list

```
TTdf_list <- list()
```

Than a function that takes ** df_list**; then creates a test and train from each data frame from df_list. Once that is complete it stores it back in **TTdf_list**.

```
# splitdf function will return a list of training and testing sets

splitdf <- function(dataframe) {

 for(i in 1:length(df_list)){

df <-  df_list$'i'

# creating the logic to divide the df, train(0.70) & test (0.3)
#ind <- sample(2, nrow(df), replace = TRUE, prob =c(0.7,0.3))

#Sample Indexes
indexes <- sample(1:nrow(df), size=0.3*nrow(df))

# Split data
test = df[indexes,]

train = df[-indexes,]

TTdf_list $'i' <- list(train,test)

 }
 return(TTdf_list);
}



 df_list<-lapply(RDD_df, splitdf)
```

Than you

Comment: `df_list$'i'` don't work as you expected. Use `[[`

Comment: Thanks akrun but df_list is retuning 3 list each with 6 members? but I only want 3 list with 2 list in them i.e. first data frame from original divided into test and train, this process applies to all them. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is just a bit simpler than what you are doing, although very much along the same lines.

```
# list of three data.frames
set.seed(1)    # for reproducibble example
lst    <- split(iris, sample(3,nrow(iris),replace=TRUE))

# list of three lists, each containing a train and test df with *approx* 70/30 split
get.TT <- function(df) setNames(split(df, sample(2,nrow(df),replace=TRUE,p=c(0.7,0.3))),
                                c("train","test"))
TTlst  <- lapply(lst, get.TT)
sapply(TTlst, function(ll) sapply(ll, nrow))
#        1  2  3
# train 27 44 40
# test  15 16  8
```

Note that `sample(..., p=...)` will return a sample with *approximately* the proportions in `p`. If you need *exactly* those proportions, use this:

```
# list of three lists, each containing a train and test set with *exactly* 70/30 split
get.TT <- function(df) setNames(split(df, (1:nrow(df)) %in% sample(nrow(df),0.3*nrow(df))),
                                c("train","test"))
TTlst  <- lapply(lst, get.TT)
sapply(TTlst, function(ll) sapply(ll, nrow))
#        1  2  3
# train 30 42 34
# test  12 18 14
```

As to why your code isn't working (other than using the incorrect syntax): your function accepts and argument `dataframe` but you never use it.

Comment: Thank jilhoward; what does setNames() do here? if you dont mind me asking. I just realized I was making life diffuclt for my self by using for loop instead of split. Thanks again

Comment: `setnames(...)` sets the names of an object and returns the named object. It's a shortcut for `names(obj) <- c("train","test")`

Comment: Thanks again. Is this best practice when trying to  do this kind of operation on DF?